# Getting a precompiled library external dependency error - how to include .so files in Bazel 7?

Tags: c++, build, bazel

Trying to get a simple external library to compile with Bazel - keeps failing.

Tried looking in the suggested stackoverflow answers / Google groups / docs / blogs - nothing. Feels like I'm missing something.

## Description

Taking pre-compiled **GoogleTest v1.12.1** for example.

#### File Tree

```
MODULE.bazel
deps/BUILD
deps/lib
deps/lib/libgtest.so
deps/lib/libgtest.so.1.12.1
deps/lib/libgtest_main.so
deps/lib/libgtest_main.so.1.12.1
deps/include
deps/include/gtest
deps/include/gtest/internal
deps/include/gtest/[...]
deps/include/gtest/gtest.h
source/BUILD
source/t.cpp
```

#### MODULE.bazel file

```
module(
    name = "mymodule",
)
bazel_dep(name = "hermetic_cc_toolchain", version = "2.2.3")
```

#### source/BUILD file

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_binary")

cc_binary(
    name = "t",
    srcs = [
        "t.cpp",
        ],
    deps = [
        "//dependencies:libgtest"
    ],
)
```

#### source/t.cpp file

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
int t(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

#### deps/BUILD file

```
load("@rules_cc//cc:defs.bzl", "cc_import")

cc_import(
    name = "libgtest",
    hdrs = glob(["include/gtest/**/*.h"]),
    includes = ["include/gtest"],
    shared_library = "lib/libgtest.so",
    linkopts = ["-pthread"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

## Error

running `bazel build //source:t` fails with:

```
INFO: Analyzed target //source:t (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
ERROR: /source/BUILD: Compiling source/t failed: (Exit 1): c++ failed: error executing CppCompile command (from target //source:t)

source/t.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'gtest/gtest.h' file not found
    1 | #include "gtest/gtest.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Target //source:t failed to build
ERROR: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

What am I missing here?

## Info

- Bazel 7.0.1
- GoogleTest v1.12.1

Answer (score 0):

The line

```py
    includes = ["include/gtest"],
```

causes `deps/include/gtest` to be placed on the compiler include path. Therefore, `#include "gtest/gtest.h` searches for `deps/include/gtest/gtest/gtest.h`, which is indeed not found. The line should likely be amended to

```py
    includes = ["gtest"],
```

.

Stepping back, it would likely be better to use the [Bazel setup recommended in the gtest documentation](https://google.github.io/googletest/quickstart-bazel.html) if possible.

Comment: Hey Benjamin :) thanks for the response! unfortunately this did not solve the issue. Trying to use `includes = ["gtest"],` resulted in the same error. I added the `--verbose_failures` flag to the `bazel build` command to see the compilation line - as expected this only makes a difference between having `-Iinclude/gtest` and `-Igtest`, but I get the same error.

I think the question I'm really asking is why is this so difficult to include a precompiled c++ library in Bazel? theoretically all I have to do is add the `.so` and header files, right?

Do you maybe have a working example? :)

Comment: Also - thanks for the setup suggestion :) unfortunately it refers to external dependencies which are already Bazel repos by themselves (perhaps using `googletest` as the example was confusing - sorry about that). I'm trying to get any `.so` and headers to work. My project has ~20 external precompiled dependencies, which are not Bazel repos at the moment.